# Problem on local compactness

Tags: general-topology

I’m working on a problem from Kelley’s book.

> If $X$ is a Hausdorff space and $Y$ is a dense locally compact subspace, Then $Y$ is open.

I supposed that if $Y$ is closed and since it’s dense, it follows that $Y=\bar{Y}=X$. But I don’t have any idea how to get contradiction. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Remember that not being open doesn't mean being closed.

Comment: @Mateo I know what I wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any $y\in Y$. From the local compactness, there is an open (relative in $Y$) neighbourhood $Y\cap U$ (where $U$ is open in $X$) of $y$ such that $K:=\mathrm{cl}_Y(Y\cap U)\subset Y$ is compact. Since $X$ is Hausdorff and $K$ is its compact subset, $K$ is closed in $X$. Therefore $U\setminus K$ is open in $X$.

We know that $Y$ is dense, so it has nonempty intersection with any nonempty open set. However $$(U\setminus K)\cap Y = (U\cap Y)\setminus K=\emptyset$$ (the last equality follows from the definition of $K$). Therefore $U\setminus K=\emptyset$, which implies that $U\subset K\subset Y$.

We managed for any point $y\in Y$ find an open neighbourhood $U\subset Y$. This shows that $Y$ is open.